# Why can I assign a value of different type to a variable?

Tags: go

In the book "Go in Action", the author wrote "Values of two different types can’t be assigned to each other, even if they’re compatible".

For example, we can't assign `Duration` to `int64` or `int64` to `Duration`.

But this is not always true, the following assignment would work like the `X` value is converted back to `[]int` automatically:

```
type X []int
var v []int = X([]int{1, 2, 3})
```

What's the difference between these two situations?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'll refer you to the [spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) and excerpt the most meaningful lines here:

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to T") in any of these cases:
>
> ...
>
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a named type.

In your example the underlying type is `[]int` for each case and `[]int` is not a named type but a slice. An `int` would actually constitute a named type (predeclared in the universe block) and would have itself as an underlying type, but `[]int` is not a named type as detailed [here](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types):

> Named instances of the boolean, numeric, and string types are
>   predeclared. Composite types—array, struct, pointer, function,
>   interface, slice, map, and channel types—may be constructed using type
>   literals.
>
> Each type T has an underlying type: If T is one of the predeclared
>   boolean, numeric, or string types, or a type literal, the
>   corresponding underlying type is T itself. Otherwise, T's underlying
>   type is the underlying type of the type to which T refers in its type
>   declaration.

Therefore if you tried making `type X int` you would *not* be able to assign it to `var v int` as `int` is a named type and would not satisfy the assignability criteria given in the spec.